# Flutter firebase auth phone authentication fails even with test numbers

Tags: authentication, flutter

I am using the firebase_auth package to enable phone authentication in my flutter app. I followed firebase-flutter tutorial and set up firebase project and an app with android support.

I then created my login page by following the firebase_auth example code, but I am getting the following error with sample number/code provided in example

```
PlatformException(error, Cannot create PhoneAuthCredential without either verificationProof, sessionInfo, ortemprary proof., null)
```

When I try verifyPhoneNumber, the following error is printed in text widget below

```
Phone authentication failed: Network error
```

.. and my network is all fine.

Comment: Did you try on a real device or only with the emulator?

Comment: A real device, Samsung S5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really an answer, but I have worked on the demo example. The additional steps were to create a Firebase app, created SHA1 fingerprint, applied json to android app directory, and didn't follow firebase android gradle settings. The other thing that was done was setting up Authentication with phone in Firebase. The example worked away perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was verifying in a page and signing in on another page. Thus, I'm creating two instances of my Authentication Service which include an object of FirebaseAuth.instance
I think "FirebaseAuth.instance" is not a singleton and it returns different object every time you call it.

My solution was making my AuthService a Singleton, to make sure calling "FirebaseAuth.instance" one time for "verifyPhoneNumber" and "signInWithPhoneNumber".

The following is the code, FYI, I'm using the context for the navigation.

```
class AuthService {  
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  static AuthService _authService;
  static AuthService of(context)  {
    if(_authService == null) _authService = AuthService(context);
    else _authService.context = context;
    return _authService;
  }

  BuildContext context;
  AuthService(this.context);

  // your code for "verifyPhoneNumber" and "signInWithPhoneNumber"...... 
}
```

## Update 1

Also please note that it the verificationId or smsCode is null of empty you will get the same error message.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I got it working by going through the demo.

Answer (score 2):

If this plugin has never worked for you, especially for phone auth, it is usually a configuration issue. I would get the example app working first and resolve all the configuration issues, before using in your app. 
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/firebase_auth/example

Comment: Ok sure, let me do that first. Thanks.

Comment: Glad u got it working. For others configuring firebase_auth package for the first time, I provided configuration steps I took to get example app working when phone auth feature was still a pull request. These steps should still apply minus the step to check out the pull request (since package is now released with the phone auth feature). https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/606#issuecomment-402878854